# Неправильно работает скрипт отбора IP

Tags: php

В массиве `$ip_list` содержаться значения подсетей которые мне нужно убрать из списка. Убираю следующим скорее всего кривым способом.

```
$ip_list = array("37.13.","217.118.","207.46.");
$top = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM logs ORDER BY ip DESC');
$top->execute();
while ($toppost = $top->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    $array[] = $toppost->ip;
}



for ($i = 0; $i <= count($ip_list); $i++){
    for ($a = 0; $a <= count($array); $a++){
        $b = explode(".", $array[$a]);
        $n = $b[0].".".$b[1].".";
            if ($ip_list[$i] == $n){        

            }
            else{
                echo $n."<br/>";
            }
    }
}
```

Но, он все равно выводит ненужные адреса, хотя в условии `if` я ничего не прописал. Что не так я сделал?)

Comment: попробуйте WHERE ip NOT LIKE '37.13.%'

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так

```
$ip_list = array("37.13.","217.118.","207.46.");
$query='SELECT DISTINCT ip FROM logs WHERE 1=1';
foreach($ip_list as $ip){
     $query .= ' AND ip NOT LIKE "'.$ip.'%"';
}
$query .= 'ORDER BY ip DESC';
$top = $pdo->prepare($query);
$top->execute();
```